# Non Modal functions, alert appearing at the top of the page in a red banner

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

When I click on the button I want the text to show up at the top of the webpage, in a red banner. I have looked on google and youtube and can't find a solution anywhere.If anyone could take a look a my code to see how I could make this work please!

```
<html>


<head>

<title> Non-Modal Alert Messages</title>


                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nonmodal1.css">


                <script type = "text/javascript">



                                    function reveal(){


                                    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML='You have touched the button!'}

                                    function hide(){
                                    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML=''  }



    </script>

</head>






            <body>



                    <form> 

<input type = "button" onclick = "reveal()" value = "Button">

<input type = "button" onclick = "hide()" value = "Close Alert">
</form>


<div id = "theDiv">

</div>

</body>




<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

Your code works for me as is, mostly.  You just need to add style information for the div, and put it first in the DOM hierarchy so that it appears at the top.  There are other ways to handle this that might be more appropriate, though, like using static positioning for the div, so it's always at the top of the window, and toggling its visibility when you want to show it.

```
<html>
<head>

    <title> Non-Modal Alert Messages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nonmodal1.css">


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function reveal() {
            document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = 'You have touched the button!'
        }

        function hide() {
            document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = ''
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="theDiv" style="background-color: red; color: white;">
    </div>

    <form>
        <input type="button" onclick="reveal()" value="Button">
        <input type="button" onclick="hide()" value="Close Alert">
    </form>
</body>
```